# How to obtain pseudo-parameters user data with AWS CDK?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-cdk

I would like to convert this working CloudFormation Code into a proper Python AWS CDK version. The EC2 shall be launched within a VPC. The user data are used to install apps. After completion, I need a call back to Cloudformation.

```
UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          <script>
          cfn-signal.exe --exit-code 0 --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource EC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region}
          </script>
```

I tried to use the direct way with `aws_cdk.core.Fn.base64` which is not working with regard to pseudo-parameters declaration within the EC2 the user data.

This is my current state:

```
EC2InstanceUserData = aws_ec2.UserData.for_windows()
EC2InstanceUserData.add_commands(
   "cfn-signal.exe --exit-code 0 ",
   "--stack ",
   VpcStack.stack_id(XXX, e.g. self?), # not working
   " --resource ",
   VpcStack.get_logical_id(XXX, e.g. self?), # not working
   " --region ",
   VpcStack.region(XXX, e.g. self?) # not working
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Method 1:

Pros:

- Can take in any amount of variables, such as those defined in the context, not just those in the `core.Aws` object such as Region or Account ID.

Cons:

- You will need to prefix references to all regular variables in the `user_data.sh` script with `$!{` rather than just `${`.

#### Steps

Use a mappings dict and parse it into the [Fn.sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.core/Fn.html#aws_cdk.core.Fn.sub) function. Personally I like these declared at the top of my `user_data.sh` script rather than substituted throughout so use a double underscore as a prefix and as a suffix. Note that you still need to consider the mappings as variables rather than strings.

i.e

```
$cat user_data.sh
ACCOUNT_ID="${__ACCOUNT_ID__}"
REGION="${__REGION__}"

## Updates
yum update -y

## Fix time
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Australia/Melbourne /etc/localtime

## ECR Repo
ECR_REPO="${!ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${!REGION}.amazonaws.com/"
...
```

In my stack declaration I then place the following dict:

```
mappings = {"__ACCOUNT_ID__": self.account,
            "__REGION__": self.region}
```

And read the `user_data.sh` into the sub function, with the mappings dict as the second parameter

```
with open("user_data/user_data.sh", 'r') as user_data_h:
    # Use a substitution
    user_data_sub = core.Fn.sub(user_data_h.read(), mappings)
```

Then use the [custom attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/UserData.html#aws_cdk.aws_ec2.UserData.custom) from the UserData module.

```
# Import substitution object into user_data set
user_data = ec2.UserData.custom(user_data_sub)
```

## Method 2

Pros:

- No need to change bash syntax

Cons:

- Token variables are hard to read, and restricted to attributes of the `core.Aws` object. Such as AccountID and Region.

#### Steps

You can run print statements inside the cdk workflow to assist you in determining what the variables such as `core.Aws.ACCOUNT_ID` and `core.Aws.REGION` are evaluated to and use these inside the user_data script. (I'm writing my deployment in python and have based it from the ec2 on an existing VPC from the [aws official examples repo](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/python/existing-vpc-new-ec2-ebs-userdata).

i.e:

```
host = ec2.Instance(...)
print(core.aws.ACCOUNT_ID)
print(core.Aws.REGION)
```

I then run `cdk synth` which yields:

```
${Token[AWS::AccountId.0]}
${Token[AWS::Region.4]}
Resources:...
```

From here I can use these in my user_data script: i.e

```
#!/bin/bash
ACCOUNT_ID="${Token[AWS::AccountId.0]}"
REGION="${Token[AWS::Region.4]}"

## Updates
yum update -y

## Fix time
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Australia/Melbourne /etc/localtime
```

Note now when re-running `cdk synth` these are recognised as special by the yaml constructor (The yaml double spacing is a known cdk bug):

```
...
UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - >-
                #!/bin/bash


                # AWS vars:

                ACCOUNT_ID="
              - Ref: AWS::AccountId
              - >-
                "

                REGION="
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - >-
                "

                ## Updates
                yum update -y

                ## Fix time
                ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Australia/Melbourne /etc/localtime

                ## ECR Repo
                EC2_REPO="${ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/"
...
```

Comment: In method 1 referencing regular variables without curly braces would also work. For example, $MY_VAR instead of ${!MY_VAR}.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following to work with python

```
from aws_cdk import (
  aws_ec2,
  core
)

host = aws_ec2.Instance(...)

host.add_user_data('', join([
  'yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n',
  f'/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v -s {core.Aws.STACK_NAME} -r {host.node.default_child.logical_id}\n'
])

meta_data = {
  'config': {
    'packages': {...},
    'files': {...},
     ...
    }
}

# for adding the meta data in a way that gets synth
host.node.default_child.add_overide('Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init', meta_data)
```

This is using the `CfnInstance` object you get from `host.node.default_child`

Answer (score -1):

You can access those pseudo-params by using the core module:

```py
from aws_cdk import core

# other code...

EC2InstanceUserData = aws_ec2.UserData.for_windows()
EC2InstanceUserData.add_commands(
   "cfn-signal.exe --exit-code 0 ",
   f"--stack {core.Aws.STACK_ID}",
   f" --resource {EC2Instance}",  # Without more context, I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're wanting
   f" --region {core.Aws.REGION}",
)

# other code ...
```